# How do you select a large number of rows in Google Sheets without endless scrolling downward after selecting the first row?

Tags: google-sheets

In a spreadsheet of 40,000 rows, I want to select the first 2,500 rows to copy them to another sheet. The only way I've seen is to
select the first row and tediously scroll the
"dot" down to include all 2,500 rows. On a computer, this would be a breeze with the
Shift key. How to accomplish something similar in Android Sheets? The keyboard doesn't open unless I'm editing a cell, so any keyboard-based solution seems to be a non-starter. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like someone already has an answer!  I also had a couple of thoughts, but I'm an Excel user and I'm not completely sure G Sheets will have equivalent functionalities or not:
1) Pre-define the selection range up to the desired row as a named range, then select the range.
2) Utilize any keyboard app [example](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/de.onyxbits.remotekeyboard/) to circumvent keyboard limitation you mention (Android Excel app also has a button to bring up the on-screen keyboard).

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can select a range when using Google Sheets:

1. Select a row or cell.
2. Click the 3-dot on the top right, then select "Select cell or range".

   [image]
3. Enter your range. For example 1:2500 will select row 1 to row 2500.

   [image]
4. Click Ok. Done.

Comment: My menu does not show Accessibility Settings and does not show Select cell or range. Why would those items be missing from the menu? Thanks.

Comment: @ibc I am using version 1.19.232.06.34. Is the version the same as yours?

Comment: I am using 1.19.232.06.35.

Comment: My version seems to be a later one. Why would a later version have less functionality?

Comment: Yes, yours is a newer version compared to mine, and yet those settings don't appear.

Comment: Are other settings present except "Accessibility settings" and "Select cell or range"?

Comment: I have a menu item Create a filter. That item does not appear in your menu. So I don't have two of your items, but I have an item that you don't have.

Comment: @ibc See edit. I also have "Create a filter".

Comment: It's just very unusual for a company to remove functionality from a product. But, we' re talking about Google, a company that creates apps and later takes them away. So why not menu items?

Comment: @ibc If you other devices or if you know someone else who uses Google sheets (or who can download Google sheets on their phone), check the feature on those. I have checked on Android 7 & 8 on 2 phones and the feature is present.

Comment: I am using Android 8.1 and Sheets version ending with 35 on my phone and don't see the items. My phone is an LG Q6+. On a Samsung phone with Android 9, I installed Sheets and it is version ending with 34 and the items are also missing. So I am very confused.

Comment: @ibc Go to your phone Settings -> Accessibility, then enable at least on service. Go back to Google Sheets, you should then start seeing the missing features and functionalities. When there is no service enabled in the Accessibility settings, they don't appear.

Comment: That worked!! Thank you so much. I turned on some accessibility settings in all three areas (vision, hearing etc.), and the menu items now appear. This is really strange behavior, in my opinion. Thanks, again.

Comment: The link you sent as "Tour" took me to an article on the Verge website dealing with Android. It's not clear to me how to say thank you properly.

Comment: @ibc Here is the correct [link](https://android.stackexchange.com/tour)